# Selecting from two tables and the latest entry

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I keep running on an issue in calling from MySQL and getting what I need. I have two tables called projects and entries, what I am trying to do is get the latest time stamped entry. The SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    projects.ProjectLogo, projects.ProjectLink, projects.ProjectDescription, 
    entries.EntryNum, entries.Votes, entries.Views, entries.Update 
FROM 
    projects 
    LEFT JOIN entries 
        ON projects.ProjectID = entries.ProjectID 
        AND projects.Media = 'image' 
        AND projects.Type = 'fan-art' 
GROUP BY 
    projects.ProjectID 
ORDER BY 
    entries.Update DESC
```

The issue is that I get the results but not the latest entry, I have used MAX(entries.Update) but it does not work. Any suggestions? Why does it not work?

Comment: Are you trying to get the latest time stamp entry for each ProjectID?

Comment: Yes, the latest entry. The update column should be the one with the timestamp and it is set to the time the row was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to get the latest `Update` for every `ProjectID` on table `entries`. The result of the subquery is then join back on the two join statements providied that it will match on two columns: `ProjectID` and `Update`.

```
SELECT  projects.ProjectLogo, 
        projects.ProjectLink, 
        projects.ProjectDescription, 
        entries.EntryNum, 
        entries.Votes, 
        entries.Views, 
        entries.Update 
FROM    projects 
        INNER JOIN entries 
            ON  projects.ProjectID = entries.ProjectID 
        INNER JOIN  
        (
            SELECT  a.ProjectID, MAX(a.Update) max_val
            FROM    entries a
            GROUP   BY a.ProjectID
        ) b ON  b.ProjectID = entries.ProjectID AND
                b.max_val = entries.Update
WHERE   projects.Media = 'image' AND 
        projects.Type = 'fan-art' 
ORDER   BY entries.Update DESC
```

Comment: Thank you J W, it works beautifully, but then the issue was the inner join?

Comment: hmmm, what do you want to do? do you want to get all the records from table `Project`? or you are asking why I'm using `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: No its just I have messed around with my code to long that I could not figure out on my own what my issue was. Thank you again for your help. Now I am trying to figure out my php code and see why it doesn't work but that is my mess to fix. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to restrict the join to only the record (row) with the latest entry date.
if the pk in entries is chronologically increasing, you can use it.

```
Select p.ProjectLogo, p.ProjectLink, p.ProjectDescription, 
      e.EntryNum, e.Votes, e.Views, e.Update 
From projects p 
   Left Join entries e 
     On e.EntryId =
        (Select(Max(entryId) from entries
         where ProjectID = p.ProjectID)
Where p.Media = 'image' 
    And p.Type = 'fan-art' 
Group By p.ProjectID 
Order By e.Update Desc
```

Otherwise, you need a double nested subquery

```
Select p.ProjectLogo, p.ProjectLink, p.ProjectDescription, 
      e.EntryNum, e.Votes, e.Views, e.Update 
From projects p 
   Left Join entries e 
     On e.EntryId =
        (Select entryId from entries
         where ProjectID = p.ProjectID
            And update =
                (Select max(update) From entries
                 Where ProjectID = p.ProjectID))                        
where p.Media = 'image' 
    And p.Type = 'fan-art' 
Group By p.ProjectID 
Order By e.Update Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery to get the latest entry:

```
select projectId, max(`update`) as lastUpdate
from entries
group by projectId
```

And now, use this subquery to get what you need:

```
select ...
from 
    projects as p
    inner join entries as e on p.projectId=e.projectId
    inner join (
        select projectId, max(`update`) as lastUpdate
        from entries
        group by projectId) as me on e.`update`=me.lastUpdate
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I tested this one too, it actually works the same way. Thanks for your help

Comment: this will somehow fail because this will only show on the result where `entries.update` is equal to `suquery.lastUpdate` .

Comment: yeah I noticed, I guess I re-ran one of the former codes presented. I did get results with the other code from J W but my issue now is not the mysql query rather displaying the information using php to display in the website. That I could try and figure out on my own before I give up and ask another question.